# Increase speed of background made of tiles tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a tiling background and have 50 000 small images for the background. I tried doing it by creating a lot of images and I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64956625/tkinter-canvas-slow) that having many canvas items can be very slow. The images are only 16 by 16 and I wonder how to make it faster (it takes around a quarter second to scroll to the side currently).

Should I use one large bitmap image that I edit somehow or is there a better way to do this. I need to be able to change the tiles but only one or two at a time.

I tried only loading the ones on screen (~10 000) but it was still very slow and I had to recreate them when I went back using up even more ids.

I expect to be able to scroll the canvas without it being incredibly slow.

Comment: I recommend trying one large bitmap and then measuring the performance. It's almost certainly going to be faster.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought @BryanOakley 's advice was quite good, and I made some example code that does just that, and I think it works quite well, I was able to get about 1.05 ms update times, and that's with the `.after` call with 1 ms.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np

NUM_IMAGES = 30*300  # approx 10,000
IMAGE_FNAMES = ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png', 'd.png']
IMAGE_SIZE = 16
CANVAS_SIZE = 480

def _gt(s=0.0):
    return time.perf_counter() - s

class JonathanGassendWindow():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self._master = master
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self._master, width=CANVAS_SIZE, height=CANVAS_SIZE, bg='#FF00FF')
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.W + tk.S)
        self._images = []
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760389/
        self._bg_image = Image.new('RGB', ((NUM_IMAGES // (CANVAS_SIZE // IMAGE_SIZE)) * IMAGE_SIZE * 2, CANVAS_SIZE))
        print(self._bg_image)

        # Load image files (I only made 4, but the concept remains)
        for i in range(NUM_IMAGES):
            with Image.open(IMAGE_FNAMES[i % len(IMAGE_FNAMES)]) as img:
                img.load()
            self._images.append(img)
        # Build the bg image
        rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
        for i in range(self._bg_image.height // IMAGE_SIZE):
            for j in range(self._bg_image.width // IMAGE_SIZE):
                self._bg_image.paste(
                    self._images[rng.integers(0, len(self._images), size=(1,))[0]],
                    (j * IMAGE_SIZE, i * IMAGE_SIZE)
                )
        self._bg_photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self._bg_image)
        self._bg_handle = self._canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self._bg_photoimage, anchor=tk.N + tk.W)
        self._prev_loop = _gt()
        self._master.after(5000, self._updateloop)

    def _updateloop(self):
        self._canvas.move(self._bg_handle, -1, 0)
        s = _gt()
        dur_total = s - self._prev_loop
        self._prev_loop = s
        print(f'\rUpdate loop dur: {dur_total * 1000:6.3f} ms', end='')
        self._master.after(1, self._updateloop)


def _main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    jgw = JonathanGassendWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

That should be enough to get you started, let me know if you have any questions.